# Checking for Existing Friend Requests in Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am creating my own friend network using parse and want to check to see if a friend request has been sent from one user to another. However, it seems that when I query my parse database it takes some time to receive the information and therefore acts as if a friend request had never been made between two users even though the relationship exists already.

```
//This is the method to test to see if the request has already been sent
-(int) testForFriendRequestBetween: (NSString *) ID1 and: (NSString *) ID2
{
NSString *user1 = ID1;
NSString *user2 = ID2;


PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendRequest"];
[query1 whereKey:@"requestFrom" equalTo:user1];
[query1 whereKey:@"requestTo" equalTo:user2];
[query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects1, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        a = 0;
        NSLog(@"Error with query");
    }
    else
    {
        a = objects1.count;
        NSLog(@"%i", a);

    }}];
return a;
}

//This is where the user types in an email address to search for a friend and I test to see if request already exists
- (IBAction)sendRequest:(id)sender
{
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString *myID = currentUser.objectId;

//Look in email column and search whatever was typed into the texfield
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo: _typeEmail.text];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
{
    //If the user was found
    if (!error)
    {
            //Create a string that reads the unique ID
            NSString *friendID = object.objectId;

            //Test to see if request already exists
            int test1 = [self testForFriendRequestBetween:myID and:friendID];
            int test2 = [self testForFriendRequestBetween:friendID and:myID];

            if(test1+test2 == 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"%i", test1+test2);

                //Save request to new row
                PFObject *request = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"friendRequest"];
                request[@"requestFrom"] = myID;
                request[@"requestTo"] = friendID;
                request[@"status"] = @"pending";
                [request saveInBackground];

                //Update label
                _requestLabel.text = @"Friend Request Sent";

            } else
            {
                _requestLabel.text = @"Request Already Sent";
            }
       }

    //If user was not found
    else
    {
        //Update label
        _requestLabel.text = @"Friend Is Not Registered";
    }
}
];
}
```

The output of this in the console is:

```
2014-07-07 13:14:25.559 SignIn[11363:70b] 0
2014-07-07 13:14:25.667 SignIn[11363:70b] 14
2014-07-07 13:14:25.730 SignIn[11363:70b] 2
```

This means that it is first reporting that test1 + test2 = 0. But then it runs the first method and says that the value of test1 is 14 and the value of test2 is 2! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `testForFriendRequestBetween` has a serious bug. You return a value that does not have a valid value. If you make an asynchronous request, like you do with `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`, you can't return the result of that call synchronously (i.e. by using `return a`. Instead, your method should have a callback block with a parameter that contains the data you receive from the query. You call that callback inside the query completion block.

Here's a simple example based on your code. As you see, all the results are processed in the callback blocks. This is the only correct way when you get the data using async calls.

```
- (void)testForFriendRequestBetween:(NSString *)ID1 and:(NSString *)ID2 callback:(void (^)(NSArray  *results))completion {

     // configure the query object, etc.    

     [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects1, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            // now you can send the query results back to the caller!
            callback(objects1);
        }
     }
}


- (IBAction)sendRequest:(id)sender
{
    // set up query, etc.

   [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
    {
        //If the user was found
        if (!error)
        {
             [self testForFriendRequestBetween:myID and:friendID callback:^(NSArray *results) {
                 if(results.count == 0) { 
                      // do stuff
                 }
             }];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. How do I then implement this method in the sendRequest method? I have not dealt with callback functions.

Comment: @user3768643 in `sendRequest`, I think you really shouldn't have 2 calls to `testForFriendRequestBetween`. You need the results of both of those calls, but they're asynchronous, so making the logic work is a bit complicated. This can be done (buy sing `NSOperation`), but I recommend a simpler solution. Change your query so it checks for both scenarios (e.g. by using `PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:`. Then you only need one call. I'll update my answer to with a sample implementation of `sendRequest:`.

Comment: thanks. When I implement this I get the following error message: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"_callback". I also have another error message that reads "linker command failed with exit code 1". Good idea to perform as orQueryWithSubquery

Comment: Well, looks like you're using `_callback` somewhere, and it's not defined. Make sure you're calling the completion block correctly. In my example code above, the callback parameter is called `callback` and you call it like a regular C function: `callback(results)`